# convert integer value to string and if it fails set "##" - SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-expression

I have below line in crystal report formula, It means that if string `conversion` failed it will print `##`.

```
CStr({rptReport;1.Total},"##")
```

Now, the question is how can I achieve this by `SSRS Expression`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try something like this,

`=IIF(CStr(Fields!Total.Value),CStr(Fields!Total.Value),"##")`